# Solution to Ozone depletion-Stratospheric injection?

Tags: science-based, atmosphere, earth

In the mid-2020s scientists have realized that although the ozone layer is recovering, it is only doing so at an alarming slow rate. So they come up with an solution.

Many titanium tanks are put in a remote Antarctic base, within the ozone hole region. The tanks run on wind energy due to the extreme ambient wind speeds. They pressurize air inside them to around ~350 bars, and make high-voltage electric arcs to convert the oxygen into ozone, and the nitrogen dioxide as residue shouldn't much of a problem (would it really be though?). Then the air is left to cool down to ambient temperature.
After the tank cools down, the gas is vented out through a tall pipe (~200m). The gas coming out is so cold that it can barely decompose. The speed of the gas makes it reach the stratosphere quickly. The usage of many tanks means that the ozone hole should recover in a few months or atleast years.

Are there any issues with this design? If yes, then what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that is not the issue with the ozone layer depletion.

Ozone is already created automatically by the influence of UV radiation on oxygen. It is constantly created and destroyed, no need to pump it up.

The issue with ozone depletion is not so much lack of a material, but of poisoning. CFCs and other chemicals alter the usual chemical reactions, causing the depletion and allowing UV rays to pass.

So, what you need to do is to remove the poison, not to add more ozone (that will be poisoned too) to the mix. Ok, maybe by continously adding ozone you could mitigate the effects, but the quantity you would need would be unbelivieveble.

Answer (score 1):

Ozone is pretty unstable: it can be produced with electric discharge, true, but if you let the gas cool down you are also letting time for the decomposition to happen. And this is the first issue.

The second issue is that atmospheric circulations stops in the [troposphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_layer), which is at 6 km height in the polar regions, while the [ozone layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_layer) is located in the lower portion of the stratosphere, between 15 and 35 km.

The only human made devices which have been capable of pushing gas to the height of the ozone layer have been large nukes, like Castle Bravo or the Tsar Bomb, way more energetic than a can of compressed gas.